# Extract subtree in R

Tags: r, algorithm, tree

I have a tree represented by a `data.frame` with two columns. The first column is the node id and the second one is the parent id, considering that the root is its own parent.

For instance,

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, parent = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5))
```

corresponds to the following tree:[image]

I want to write a function

```
get_subtree <- function(new_root) {
  ...
}
```

which returns the vector of id's of nodes of the subtree whose root is `new_root`. For example, `get_subtree(2)` would return the vector `c(2,4,5,6,9,10)`. I guess it should be a recursive function which returns `new_root` if `new_root` is a leaf. I can easily get the children of a given node, using `df %>% filter(parent == new_root) %>% pull(id)` but it stops at the first generation. So how to write my function?

**NB**: I know about the package `data.tree`. I could transform my `data.frame` into a `data.tree` object using `mytree <- data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork(df[-1,])` (here I need to remove the root) and then I guess I could easily use buit-in functions to get subtrees. The problem is: my tree has more than two million nodes and `data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork`just takes too long. I just need a relatively small subtree (a few thousands nodes) so I think it's better to work on the `data.frame` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use the `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df[2:1])
as.numeric(subcomponent(g1, 2, mode = 'out'))
#[1]  2  4  5  6  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to use as_ids instead of as.numeric.